# $temp = &$xml->xpath(…). What is "&" for?

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.2

I'm looking at some old code that yields an error `Strict Notice: Only variables should be assigned by reference` on the code below on PHP 5.4.

```
$temp = &$xml->xpath(…);
```

Was the `&` ever needed in this operation in the earlier versions of PHP? `xpath()` already returns data according to current PHP documentation, so it would be assigned to `$temp`. I'm just not sure what it is or was trying to do by reference at the time it was written.

Comment: OK, I understand what passing by reference is. I still don't see what passing by reference a function that returns a value does. `xpath()` returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects. Is `$temp` supposed to be referencing that array somehow? I don't see how that would work.

Comment: A leftover from outdated sources that tried to pass the return value of a function by reference, probably to avoid copying the value (which doesn't take place in current PHP, it's copy-on-write), or to properly pass a created object in PHP 4.

Comment: @Sven, Thanks for the response! So, I can remove `&` in PHP 5.3, correct?